JQ - Using a non UTC date field and looking back a certain amount of time
I am trying to write a BASH+jq one liner to only return the entries that are less than 5 minutes old as I am writing automation to only look back 5 minutes (BASH).  Using the following JSON:
[
  {
    "id": 621024,
    "iid": 99999,
    "project_id": 999,
    "sha": "faf897sd98fa987afsd98f7",
    "ref": "master",
    "status": "running",
    "source": "push",
    "created_at": "2024-05-10T16:32:01.072-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2024-05-10T16:32:03.565-04:00",
    "web_url": "https://gitlab/pipelines/9999",
    "name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 621023,
    "iid": 99999,
    "project_id": 999,
    "sha": "faf897sd98fa987afsd98f7",
    "ref": "master",
    "status": "success",
    "source": "push",
    "created_at": "2024-05-10T16:31:47.951-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2024-05-10T16:35:30.362-04:00",
    "web_url": "https://gitlab/pipelines/9999",
    "name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 621020,
    "iid": 99999,
    "project_id": 999,
    "sha": "faf897sd98fa987afsd98f7",
    "ref": "master",
    "status": "waiting_for_resource",
    "source": "push",
    "created_at": "2024-05-10T15:27:00.248-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2024-05-10T15:30:14.172-04:00",
    "web_url": "https://gitlab/pipelines/9999",
    "name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 621019,
    "iid": 99999,
    "project_id": 999,
    "sha": "faf897sd98fa987afsd98f7",
    "ref": "master",
    "status": "success",
    "source": "push",
    "created_at": "2024-05-10T14:26:02.235-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2024-05-10T14:29:45.406-04:00",
    "web_url": "https://gitlab/pipelines/9999",
    "name": null
  }
]

My challenge is that the date being returned for created_at is in EST
I have been trying to use some of the traditional time functions/tools with jq but dont think its working because they expect the date to check against to be in UTC
I know I can take off the milliseconds using something like
jq  '.[] | .created_at |= .[0:19]'
But that still leaves me with a timestamp that is in EST.
"created_at": "2024-05-10T15:27:00"
All the documentation I read talks about needing the date to be in ISO 8601 to be parsable with some of date/time functions.  I dont know what to add to my jq that would subtract only selecting the entries that are less than 5 minutes old
This query fails:
jq  '.[] | .created_at |= .[0:19] | select(.created_at | fromdate - 300)'
with error
jq: error (at <stdin>:55): date "2024-05-10T16:32:01" does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"

Re "My challenge is that the date being returned for created_at is in EST", EDT, actually. EST is -5. EDT is -4.

Either use the Go implementation of jq, which can parse %z correctly:
gojq '
  map(select(
    .created_at | sub("\\.[0-9]+"; "")
    | strptime("%FT%T%z") | now - mktime <= 300
  ))
'

Or manually interpret the (numeric) timezone (as (+|-)HH[:]MM), and do the math:
map(select(
  .created_at | sub("\\.[0-9]+"; "")
  | ( capture(".{19}(?<d>[+-])(?<h>[0-9]{2}):?(?<m>[0-9]{2})")
      | .d += "1" | .[] |= tonumber
    ) as $tz
  | strptime("%FT%T%z") | .[3] -= $tz.d * $tz.h | .[4] -= $tz.d * $tz.m
  | now - mktime <= 300
))


WOW! thank you for the quick and thorough response.  I can't control the version of jq that is used so I went with the 2nd option. worked.

any chance you could break down what each of those pipes is doing in the 2nd jq option?

@JuanD capture matches the input against a given regex pattern (here: 19 chars, then a + or a - sign, followed by two digits, an optional colon, and another two digits). The result is an object with some parts (the sign and the two digit blocks) extracted as strings into fields, using labels (from the angle brackets) as key names. .d += "1" then appends the character 1 to the sign, so all three fields can now safely be converted into actual numbers using tonumber (a sign by itself would fail). Later, the hour and minute parts of the broken-down time are updated using those numbers.

ok. I think thats making sense. how about the last pipe? now - mktime <= 300 i assumed that was 300 seconds (5 minutes)? ive been playing with that time and not sure thats the case?

@JuanD Yes, select either keeps or discards its input (the object processed) depending on its boolean argument, while now - mktime <= 300 evaluates to true or false depending on whether or not the current time in seconds since the Epoch provided by now is at most 300 seconds (or 5 minutes) higher than the one mktime produces based on the previously calculated broken-down time. To have dynamic limits, use jq --argjson limit 300 '… now - mktime <= $limit …'

Thanks so much for all your time with this. I think whats throwing me is that I have been trying this query and not sure if its working as intended.
At 22:36 in EDT I ran the query with a limit of 60 assuming that nothing over 60 seconds would appear. however it returned an entry whose created_at was:
"created_at": "2024-05-13T22:18:16.031-04:00",
Not sure why anything over a minute would have been returned?
Additional info, if I echo $TZ on the system its: America/New_York

@JuanD To debug the actual timestamps processed, try changing mktime to (mktime|debug), then compare them to the current timestamp (to print that use now again, e.g. map(…), now). As we're only dealing with timestamps at this point, the actual value of the environment variable TZ doesn't matter (it'd only matter if you used one of jq's *local* filters anyway). -- To test the decoding, you could simply check if date +%FT%T%:z | jq -R '(capture(…) | …) as $tz | strptime("%FT%T%z") | … | now - mktime' is small enough (it should only contain the overhead, i.e. be less than a second).

i did not know about using debug like that. thank you. While doing some additional googling i ran into this great youtube video that helped demo some of these date/time filters it also had a nice pastebin for all the code.
with that info i tried 2 things:
I changed now to (now | todate | fromdate) in that last pipe.
and i am now using updated_at as the field to look back 5 minutes against (it seemed to make more sense)
so far things are looking more accurate
